# Which SQL function can solve my query? Combine multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tabels (Files,Users,Files_Users)

Files Table A

| Id | File Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

Users Table B

| Id | User Name | is_internal | is_external |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | john | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Caren | 0 | 1 |

Files_Users tabel

| Id | File_Id | Int_User_Id | Ext_User_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 |

I want to show all files related to user_id = 1 only (to fill combo box in c sharp winfroms)
my Approach was :

```
select 
A.Id,
File_Name 
from 
Files A,
Users B
where 
A.Id = B.File_Id and
Ext_Emp_Id = 1 OR Int_Emp_Id = 1
```

but it display all the five files in files table and repeatedly,

I expected to show the 1st 3 files names only because user_id = 1 showed in Files_Users in the 3 rows

please any help is appreciated

Comment: Also specify the expected result.

Comment: A and B are poor tables aliases. Choose something that makes sense, like F for Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the explicit join syntax. Then this should do it:

```
select f.Id, f.Name 
from Files f
join Files_Users fu on fu.File_Id = f.id
join Users u on u.id in (fu.Int_User_Id, fu.Ext_User_Id)
where u.id = 1
```

Comment: Great , It worked successfully, Thanks dear juergen d